# trouble with php with $_GET

Tags: php

I have this php

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos Aires");
$data_string=$_GET['data'];
$sufijo=date("Ym");
    $nombreArchivo = "datos".$sufijo.".txt";
    $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    $tamanio=strlen($data);
    $archivo = fopen($nombreArchivo, "a");
    fwrite($archivo, $data ." -".$tamanio."- ".$hoy .PHP_EOL);
    fclose($archivo);

 ?>
```

I'm getting this suddenly

Warning: Undefined variable $data in /www/6539138ca6dfa/mydomain.com.ar/public/datosgprs.php on line 8

Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /www/6539138ca6dfa/mydomain.com.ar/public/datosgprs.php on line 8

Warning: Undefined variable $data in /www/6539138ca6dfa/mydomain.com.ar/public/datosgprs.php on line 10

And doesn't work.
Works fine until 3 days ago. What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

reduce the code to a minimum, try isset but the error continues.
It just have to paste what you receive by GET into a text file

Comment: Looks like you didn't define `$data`.  Did you mean `$data_string`?

Comment: You read from `$data` but never create it. That couldn't possibly be working 3 days ago, perhaps you've just enabled error reporting.

Comment: It seems like you don't have a variable called `$data`. I do, however, see one called `$data_string`.

Comment: Another possibility is that you had a very ancient PHP version and upgraded it 3 days ago. Converting GET parameters to variables was removed from PHP years ago.

Comment: Check whether `register_globals=on` in your php config file

Comment: @KenLee Just be aware that `register_globals` was [removed in PHP/5.4](https://www.php.net/releases/5_4_0.php), released [in 2012](https://prototype.php.net/versions/#php_5.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare variable $data that's why you are getting this error *(undefined variable $data)*

Comment: I'm sorry!!!! my mistake